# can't ssh:unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password or master process exited unexpectedly

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I have problem with perl modules, i 'm trying to connect to the remote server using the OpenSSH module from CPAN and i have given the username and password correctly but when i run my CGI from browser i see the following error message "

> can't ssh:unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password or
>   master process exited unexpectedly

in need of immediate reply's and awaiting,
Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Net::OpenSSH;


my $query = CGI->new();
#my $mach_name=$query->param('mach_name');
my $mach_name= '****.cce.***.com';
my $user='root';
my $passwd='*******';
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$mach_name",user => "$user" , passwd => "$passwd
", master_opts => [-o => "strictHostKeyChecking=no"]);
$ssh->error and die "can't ssh:" . $ssh->error;
my $mem_info =$ssh->capture("ioscan -m lun");
print "$mem_info";
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>test page</title></head>\n";
print "<body><p>Dicovering Machine Please wait....</p>\n";
print "<p>$mach_name</p>";
print "<p><b>Swap Memory :$mem_info </b> </p>";
print "</body></html>";
```

The same program if i run through the command line it is getting the o/p but through the browser i'm seeing the above error i have given the passwd and username correctly

Comment: Follow the trouble-shutting section on the module documentation

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved when I've increased the timeout from 10 seconds to 15 seconds, because the device is using an older SSH daemon version, but my linux server that made the client connection is upgraded and of course it probes first the newer ciphers.

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
$host,
port                => $port,
user                => $user,
password            => $pass,
timeout             => 15,       # <= this was 10 and now is 15
kill_ssh_on_timeout => 1,
strict_mode         => 0,
master_opts         => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", '-vvv'], #<= -vvv helped much
ctl_dir             =>'/tmp/libnet-openssh-perl',
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some permissions issue. Run `ssh` in `verbose mode`:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$mach_name",
                             user => "$user", 
                             passwd => "$passwd",
                             master_opts => '-vvv',
                             master_stderr_fh => \*LOG);
```

If that doesn't give you enough information about the cause of the problem, then, you can use [**truss**](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/truss/) to see what's happening at the OS level.

Also check `.ssh/known_hosts`, make sure `.ssh` directory is writeable by Apache. `.libnet-openssh-perl` directory should be writeable by Apache.

For example, my Apache user is `apache` with a home directory of `/var/www`
I have `/var/www/.ssh` owned by `apache`, and `/var/www/.libnet-openssh-perl` owned by `apache`. I ssh to devices using my own account, then copy my `known_hosts` file to `/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: open_ex: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/.libnet-openssh-perl/root-k8sn1.cce.hp.co-29356-315770','-l','root','k8sn1.cce.hp.com','--']
# _waitpid(29359) => pid: 29359, rc: Interrupted system call
# open_ex: ['ssh','-S','/.libnet-openssh-perl/root-k8sn1.cce.hp.co-29356-315770','-l','root','k8sn1.cce.hp.com','--','ioscan -m lun']
# _waitpid(29360) => pid: 29360, rc: Interrupted system call this is what i'm seeing in the debug mode and i see the last coloumn is empty and i though null was passing and tried to remove passwd and executed the cgi but no response and not able to see errors.. any i/p.?

Comment: i have removed the password of the target machine and tried to execute then i see no response i'm getting.

Comment: Hi it has all sort of permissions can any one solve this it is blocking my work.