# While SSH'ing following error occures - unable to establish master SSH connection: master process exited unexpectedly

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I have a script which does ssh to number of servers (`@alive_hosts`) stored in an array and executes certain commands on those hosts (these hosts are IP address).

```
...
use Net::Ping;
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
 
#these hosts are the IP addresses
my @hosts = ("host1", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5"); 

my $p = Net::Ping->new();

foreach my $hostname (@hosts){
    my ($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($hostname);
    push (@alive_hosts, $hostname) if $ret;
}

my $ssh;
my $command = "perl -e "print \"Hello..\"";

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
 
LOOP:
foreach my $n (@alive_hosts) {
  my $pid = $pm->start and next LOOP;
 
  #doing ssh to the host and running the command
  #lets say here I am executing simple Perl command 
  $ssh = Connect($n, "user", "passwd");
  $ssh->capture($command);
 
  $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
undef $ssh;

sub Connect {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user=>$user, password=>$passwd);
    $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: " . $ssh->error;
    return $ssh;
}
...
```

When I execute this script, I am getting below error after certain time.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'host5' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Couldn't establish SSH connection: unable to establish master SSH connection: master process exited unexpectedly at script.pl ....
```

Actually `$command` is able to run in host1 to host4. But when it takes host5, its unable to run it.
I could able to ping host5 and connecting looks fine to me. But through the script it always fails to execute the command.

1. I have tried putting `master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", '-vvv']` in `$ssh` object in `Connect()` subroutine.
2. In capture, I added timeout period like this - `$ssh->capture({timeout = 10}, $command);`
   But didn't succeeded in both the cases.

ssh version: `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

Any idea why it's failing to run command in last host always?

Comment: If you reduce the number of forks to 1 and only connect with `host5` do you get the same error?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Let me try and confirm.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I don't get the error. But strange issue is sometimes it happens to `host3`, `host4` too.

Comment: I have added the timeout period while connecting to the host in `Connect` subroutine, like which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220215/6124824). But no luck :|

Comment: The module is able to produce lots of debugging information. See the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#DEBUGGING).

Comment: As you are using password authentication, the problem could also be a race condition during the pty allocation. Which OS is in the host machine?

Comment: @salva I exchanged keys to become it be password less authentication. Still I could see the issue. OS is `Linux version 2.6.32-754.30.2.el6.x86_64 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)`

Comment: @salva Also I could able to print logs in debug.txt (as you mentioned in previous comment). The logs I am unable to understand.  Is there any documentation to read meaning of these logs.

Comment: No, but append the debugging output to your post so that we can see it.

Comment: @salva Ah, okay. Will try that.

Comment: @salva I could able to produce the debug logs. If you see them after `Next authentication method: password..` it should print `packet_send2...` but in certain server it says `Couldn't establish SSH connection...` where the SSH to the server is being failed. Here is the log [link](https://privatebin.net/?daba2c4d47c9007c#C8D2sP9KuKVaQLdrpVdHS39dES4y7J96EqnbuHTxn9iz)