# Retry SSH to Host if Connection to the Host Fails in Perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I have a script, which does SSH to the server and execute some command (In this script, for demonstration I am running Perl print statement with Hello message).

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;

$Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;

BEGIN {
  open my $out, '>', '/tmp/debug.txt' or warn $!;
  $Net::OpenSSH::debug_fh = $out;
  $Net::OpenSSH::debug = -1;
}

my @hosts = ("ipaddress1","ipaddress2");

my $ssh;
my $command = "perl -e 'print \"Hello..\"'";

foreach my $n (@hosts) {
    
  #Here if connection to the host($n) fails, is it possible to retry again
  $ssh = Connect($n, "user", "passwd"); 
  $ssh->capture($command);

  print "Done execution in Host: $n\n";
 
}

undef $ssh;
print "**End**\n";

sub Connect {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user=>$user, password=>$passwd);
    $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: " . $ssh->error;
    return $ssh;
}
```

Whenever I execute this script, sometimes it successfully prints below message:

```
Done execution in Host: ipaddress1
Done execution in Host: ipaddress2
**End**
```

But sometimes cannot do ssh to host (either `ipaddress1` or `ipaddress2`) and gives following message:

```
Couldn't establish SSH connection: unable to establish master SSH connection: master process exited unexpectedly at script.pl ....
```

Its being get died in `Connect` subroutine (cause I couldn't trace, opened question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64450923/while-sshing-following-error-occures-unable-to-establish-master-ssh-connectio)).

So, is there any way if I cannot connect(ssh) to the host, retry can be done after certain period of time (for `n` number times) instead of printing error message and make the script die?

Comment: Since you have written the code that will cause it to `die`, why not catch it as an exception by wrapping the `Connect` call in an `eval { ... Connect(...); capture(); }; if($@) { exception happened }`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo okay. In this case what would be the retry limit for `eval`. And let's say if I have passed incorrect `user` or `passwd` what could be the outcome? How many times it will try to connect.

Comment: The `eval { ... }; if($@) { ... }` is just a way to do exception handling in perl, like `try { ... } catch(...) { ... }` in other languages. What you _do_ when you catch the exception is up to you. You could decrease a counter and stop after a few tries like in the answer you've gotten below (that does it without exception handling).

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSH provides a nice interface for errors. I'd start by looking at the examples on the [cpan page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH). Try the following

```
 foreach my $n (@hosts) {
    
  #Here if connection to the host($n) fails, is it possible to retry again
  $ssh = Connect($n, "user", "passwd", 3); 
  $ssh->capture($command);

  print "Done execution in Host: $n\n";
 
}

undef $ssh;
print "**End**\n";

sub Connect {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd , $retry_limit ) = @_;
    my $timeout = 10;
    my $con;
    while ( $retry_limit-- > 0 )
    {
        $con = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, 
            user=>$user, 
            password=>$passwd,
            timeout=> $timeout,
            );
        last unless $con->error();
    }
    die "unable to connect ".$con->error() if retry_limit <0;
    return $con;
}
```

Comment: It looks okay to me perl -e 'my $rt =3; while ($rt<3) {print "$rt,"; } print "* $rt *";'  the -- is done after the compare, if it was --$retry_limit is would do it beforehand.  you do spot one bug in the code though. $retry_limit is -1 after 3 failures, not 0!

Comment: Yes, changing that would work too. It'll be `-1` upon failure if you keep the post increment operator. It's i.m.o. a bit more straight forward to use the same value in the loop as after which means that you can use the implicit conversion to boolean in both places and do `while(--$retry_limit) { ... } die "..." unless ($retry_limit);` but sure, `> 0` and `< 0` works.

Comment: Agreed, probably be the clearest to have `die "unable to connect ".$con->error() if $con->error();`

Comment: Yeah, that's probably an even better option - or just return from inside the loop if a connection succeeds. `return $con unless $con->error;` - no need to check anything after the loop - just `die`.